# Open Graph ticker localization

Tags: internationalization, facebook-opengraph

My app adds lines like this to the ticker "[User] read [article] on [app]". I'd like to have that translated into Danish for users that use Facebook in Danish, so I've added this to the meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="da_DK" />
```

The name of the object is "read", and the action is "article".

Unfortunately, the ticker line isn't shown in Danish, just English. How do I make it do that? I've already read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/, but I can't get it to work. Is it possible that the action/object just haven't been translated into Danish by whomever translates Facebook? If so, how do I confirm that?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug returns no error for the page, and the language tag seems to be correctly parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this kind of translation is done in the Facebook Translations app.

Go into your app settings, click edit, and on the left there will be a link to "Translate your App" - in this tool, you'll be able to specify the non-English structure of News Feed and Ticker stories.

The object itself (title etc) in Danish will be picked up from your object URL.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the **Translations Admin Panel**, tab **Browse Phrases**, column **Status**, reachable under:

```
https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php?app={APP_ID}&aloc={LOCALE_YOU_TRANSLATE_TO}
```

What should then be the right value for this column? I have *I approved* at the moment and translations are not visible in the OpenGraph messages appearing in the Ticker or on the Timeline.